# Why didn't Spain and Portugal become industrial powerhouses in the 20th century?

Tags: world-war-two, economy, world-war-one, spain, portugal

Although Spain experienced a gruesome civil war, neither Spain nor Portugal participated in either the first or the second world wars. Despite their losses of millions of people, widespread destructionist of infrastructure and industry and -in some cases- even hefty reparation payments, other European countries have largely been more populous and prosperous than either Portugal and republican/nationalist Spain throughout most of the 20th century. Why?

Comment: Long dictatorships are far worse for the economy and development of a country than short wars, no matter how bitter and destructive. After WWII the Marshal plan helped rebuild the european economy - including that of Germany. Spain was spared, Portugal ignored.

Comment: If Portugal did not participate in WWI, how did it lose over 10K soldiers? Why does every Portuguese town seem to have a WWI memorial?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Clashes with Germany over African claims

Comment: @Hefewe1zen Mostly. But also due to the Ludendorff Offensive, which was not in Africa.

Comment: What *is* a "industrial powerhouse"? Hint: *Is* the UK one? –– https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portugal_during_World_War_I –– I'd suggest you define more closely what kind of economic indicators, prosperity or development you are looking for and want compared; to what and whom. What has your own research revealed to you?

Comment: @Rekesoft that looks like the core of an answer.  Please don't answer in comments.

Comment: My question, while maybe not so clear, was mainly about estimates on GDP and population of countries prior and after WW2:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_regions_by_past_GDP_(PPP)#1830%E2%80%931938_(Bairoch), 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_population_in_1939

According to these estimates, Spain had a 9-10 times smaller GDP than germany, amolst 5 times smaller than france, and about the same as belgium. Population was significantly smaller as well and despite Spain having a large agricultural sector, it was not so productive and people still starved during WW1

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo : officially, Portugal remained neutral in WW1 and WW2. While I did not mean to disrespect the loss of life Portugal has experienced, my question specifically referred to population and economy in Europe, while most of the involvement of Portugal was in colonial Africa. To compare: the Ottoman Empire lost 13-15% of its population, without counting the spanish flu, germany lost 2-3 million people in WW1, and so on. That is bound to have an effect on their post-war economy, or so i thought.

Comment: @Matthaeus Portugal remained so neutral in WWI that, in February 1916, as requested by the British, Portugal arrested dozens of German and Austro-Hungarian ships docked in Portugal. Unsurprisingly, this led to official declarations of war. I am not claiming that Portugal suffered a lot in WWI, but it was certainly not neutral.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo You are right, i was mistaken, Portugal did -in fact- formally declare in 1916

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### You need educated population, industrial and technological base, and resources

First condition is simple to understand - you need engineers and qualified workers for your industry, the more the better. Germany is good example for this - although they lost both world wars, German educational system (with foundations laid down in 18th century) produced some of the best scientific minds in 19th and 20th century, and German engineering was and still is considered among the best in the world. Countries like Russia and China that had large uneducated rural population tackled with this problem by creating vast array of new schools, from elementary to universities. Spain on the other hand was considered by its own admission as [backwards](https://idus.us.es/xmlui/bitstream/handle/11441/64984/Education_in_Spain_Close-up_of_Its_History_in_the_20th_Century.pdf?sequence=1) in this regard at the beginning of 20th century. Measured were taken to rectify this, but then unfortunate Civil War came and much was ruined. During the Franco rule Catholic Church had large influence on education - is that good or bad depends on your political stance. Nevertheless, in that period Spain didn't progress much better (or worse) compared to other European countries, and continued to lag behind best of them.

As for second condition, it is easier to industrialize if you already had experiences with industry :) Example for this would be Germany after WW2. Germany was almost completely devastated in the war, and divided by victors. Still, Germans did know how to create and operate effective industry. As mentioned before, they had educated workforce, but also know-how what could be done and what could not be. Therefore when they got the funds they quickly become very efficient. Compare that with Chinese Great Leap Forward and many blunders like [backyard furnaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backyard_furnace). Countries that didn't have experience with industry often made errors easily avoidable by those with knowledge. Unfortunately for Spain, until the beginning of 20th century [it was mostly agricultural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economic_history_of_Spain). Attempts of industrialization before Civil War were sporadic, and during WW2 and immediately after it there was no realistic chance to build lacking infrastructure. Only in latter years of Franco rule (from 1960's), with the help of foreign investment, industrialization in Spain picked up pace and somewhat closed the gap to world's leading economic powers.

Finally, for your industry you need raw resources to process, either domestic or imported. In latter case you would need convertible currency. Large countries like Russia, US, China etc ... usually rely on domestic resources, with some exception like for example Chinese need for oil. Mid-sized countries like Germany depend on foreign resources (this was actually one of the reasons for both WW1 and WW2 ) . After losing majority of colonies in 19th century Spain also became mid-sized country, therefore it did depend on overseas trade to acquire lots of its needs. One example would be [cotton](http://www.helsinki.fi/iehc2006/papers2/Thomson.pdf), despite domestic production Spain's textile industry depended on imports, and from 19th century these had to be paid with hard currency. Note that during WW2 (and to a much lesser extent in WW1) many critical materials could not be imported at all, because of naval blockade and submarine warfare. After WW2 Spain was largely isolated as it was seen as pro-Axis, this changed only in 50's when Spain accepted US bases on its soil in exchange for capital inflows.

Answer (score 8):

I cannot give you a definitive answer, but I think some of the general ideas are flawed:

- Starting point: You should not understimate the differences at the beginning of the 20th century between Spain and Portugal in one side and France, the UK and Germany in the other.
- War is only destruction: Yes, there is a lot of destruction in a war. But it also gives the government an opportunity to mobilize all the economy towards its aims (sky high taxes, promotion of strategic industries, forced labor, etc.)
- War damages are permanent: Yes, a bombing campaign can be devastating on the infrastructure. Yet after the war is over, if you have a well formed workforce industrialization can happen relatively quickly (and even better, due to more far reaching modernization than otherwise possible)
- Wars are long: WWI meant a boom for the Spanish industry, but it only lasted four years. Four years may look like a lot of time, but if you have very little basic industry and infrastructure it is difficult to significantly expand it in that time.
- You ignore internal factors: During WWI, the high price paid for goods by the countries at war meant that prices did raise in Spain, too, leading to the [Crisis of 1917](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_crisis_of_1917). During WWII, Spain was devoid of any industry worth mentioning due to the Spanish Civil War.
- Wars do not affect neutral countries: With all the capital and resources of the major countries being used up at war, there were little resources to spare to build new industries in Spain. And of course, embargos and submarine warfare can affect neutral countries, too. And usually neutral countries end up spending more in their own militaries to try to protect against a possible involvement in the war.
- Industrialization spreads: Well, it somehow does. But there is a bonus for building factories at places that already have all the infrastructure, suppliers, customers and workforce needed; there is an incentive to concentrate the industry. In the end, millions of Spanish workers emigrated to the industrial centers of Europe because it was easier (or cheaper) than building new industrial centers in Spain or Portugal.
- Also, you are forgetting both the Marshall Plan, the Spanish Civil War (which was quite crippling) and the Spanish War in Morocco. Portugal was somewhat more peaceful, but it also fought some colonial wars (Goa, Angola, Mozambique).

Comment: This looks like a well constructed challenge to the frame of the question. +1

Comment: To be fair: i did mention the civil war. However the loss of population and the toll on cities was not nearly as great as other world-war affected european countries experienced it.

Comment: @Matthaeus which is another factor to why they had less need to industrialize; they didn't have as much to rebuild.

Comment: I would say that spain and portugal didn't experience a rapid growth in population as Italy.

Answer (score 4):

**Because they were dictatorships**

Both of those countries were repressive dictatorships until quite recently. 1976 in Portugal's case, and Spain redemocratized during 1975-78. That's recent enough that I remember watching [Saturday Night Live Weekend Update skits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalissimo_Francisco_Franco_is_still_dead) about both as they were happening.

It's [not impossible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meiji_Restoration) for that kind of government to produce robust and stable economic expansion, but it would be [highly unusual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictatorship#Dictatorships_in_Africa_and_Asia_after_World_War_II). Far more typical (and really, human) is for the people in power to mostly line their own pockets, at the expense of the nation.

According to economists Papaioannou and Luiten van Zanden, there's a [measurable economic retarding effect](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-institutional-economics/article/dictator-effect-how-long-years-in-office-affect-economic-development/8CD2D9DB399B528C23D55D2C9B46C8B5) with *long-running* dictatorships, reducing growth, increasing inflation, and weakening institutions, which they termed ***The Dictator Effect***. The dictators in Spain and Portugal both ruled for *36 years* (although Portugal's regime lasted another 7).

Comment: Soviet Union and China are examples of dictatorships that created industrial centers. Based on the theory of "Why nations fails", a dictatorships still can create economic grow for a while.

Comment: @Santiago - Both of those countries were authoritarian to be sure but not Dictatorships of the kind studied in the paper I linked. There are real differences between the two.

Comment: No. This is so oversimplified as to be called wrong quite rightfully. Whether Mao or Deng, Stalin or Brezhnev, they were dictators, the economic policy and outcome were still *vastly* different. And the difference between the successes of Stalin and Deng are the most instructive here. Reading that paper closely reveals the key term is not 'dictator' (evoking smells of sulphur) but "long term tenure" (including *structures* that sclerotise power, and eliminate feedback lines for fast adaptions).

Comment: Compare that effect of long tenure: Reagan-Bush, Erdogan, Thatcher-Major, Adenauer+Kohl,  Paul Biya, Mbasogo, Museveni, Mbasogo, Putin. Which of these is 'wholly democratic', and in which case have we seen relative economic decline over time? And compared to what, ie external factors, like worldwide recession, boycotts, sanctions and economic wars? The terms of trade build upon path dependencies as well. For this Q, a critique of https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricardian_model would yield quite some insights.

Comment: @LangLangC - Have to strongly disagree there. One important feature of a Dictatorship is that there's no real structure of power outside of the Dictator himself. Generally there's either no clear successor, or its expected to be one of his kids. This has a very real impact on how things are run. Now look at the USSR. Brezhnev in fact replaced Khrushchev when the latter was deemed to be performing unsatisfactorily by the Politburo. This shows there was a clear power center outside of the head. Same with PRC, run by a committee whose leaders have never been relatives of the previous leader.

Comment: By that measure you yourself declare the model's explanatory power and effect name of 'dictatorship' unsuitable for most applications. Mussolini, Ulbricht, Honecker, Gorbachev all ousted by their cronies. Let's look at the data for Pt: https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NY.GDP.MKTP.KD.ZG?locations=PT https://tradingeconomics.com/portugal/gdp-growth https://www.pordata.pt/en/Portugal/Real+GDP+growth+rate-2298 (still looking for better 20th cent, but compare that with US or Germany) Model=true would mean until 1975 it goes down, then it goes up?

Comment: Mussolini's ouster was implicitly an entire change of government *system* (and came days before the US Army was clearly set to do it anyway), which kind of proves the point. The others I don't believe were technically running dictatorships either. *Authoritarian* systems, perhaps, but not [dictatorships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictatorship).

Comment: The *Gran Consiglio del Fascismo* is just such a power structure outside of the dictator himself. Even Stalin feared arrest after fleeing to his datcha when *Barbarossa* came along. Mao had his dictatorship of the proletariat contested and we might argue over proper definitions of autocracy, anocracy, and then re-apply that to Franco or *Estado novo*. I maintain that the effect you cited is probably *detectable*, but far from exhaustive for an explanation and named misleadingly. In other words: the bolded part is overreaching and this A needs expansion?

Comment: +1 For the Question because the comments are interesting :)

Comment: All dictators need support of people they put in power or make rich via corruption. Can’t think of a single dictator who stayed in power simply because of who he was

Comment: @Alen - An example of something like this would be Mobutu, who tried to lay a foundation for a democratic system in Congo/Zaiere as he started to grow ill (possibly even so he could retire and concentrate on treatment), but the hierarchy of the entrenched kelptocratic state under him wouldn't allow it to have any power. He'd spent decades making the country all about him, so now the kleptocracy needed *him* to function. (Note there are alternative less favorable explanations, but this is what I'd heard from reporters who had worked there).

Comment: The record of Lenin / Stalin on industrialization and economic growth was actually quite poor.  The legend of Bolshevik modernization of Russia is just that - a legend.  Statistically Russia didn't return to the industrial output level achieved under the Czars until just before the outbreak of World War II.  And Russia's economic growth rate under the last Czars was greater than that under Lenin and Stalin.  OTOH, the Czars were certainly dictators, so Russia would still be a *general* problem for the theory of a Dictator Effect.

Comment: If dictatorships retard industrial/economic expansion, then how do you account for the pre-war economies of Germany and Italy?  Not to mention numerous other dictatorships that didn't have their economies ruined by ideologically-motivated wars?

Comment: @jamesqf - It often seems like folks are attacking this idea *without reading the link*. In particular, they found the effect is generally most pronounced the longer the dictator has been in power. They also didn't say it was an immutable law of nature, just an effect. That being said, both country's economies were complete basket cases during the period you mention (due largely to the Great Depression, not really their own doing), so I'm not real sure what you mean.